# Threading OpenCV video in GTK and keep events?

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv, gtk3, glib

I'm trying to get my camera feed into a GTK window,
and I'd like to keep the button-press-event and motion-notify-event events working.

I've found how to get the video by refreshing the image in a Gtk.image,
in a GLib.idle_add, tried with a thread.Threading, tried with a GLib.timeout_add,
but the loop is still blocking the events.
I also tried with an OpenCV-headless in a virtual environment...

I read it: https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/threading.html

What didn't I understand? Is there a way to fix this ?

Here's my (simplified) code :

```py
import cv2

import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import GLib, Gtk, GdkPixbuf
#import threading

vdo_url="http://my_cam/vdo.mjpg" # simplified, without security

class Cam_GTK(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Cam GTK")

        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(vdo_url)

        self.video = Gtk.Image.new()
        self.video.connect("button-press-event", self.on_video_clicked )
        self.video.connect("motion-notify-event", self.on_video_hover )
        # Also tried with event=Gtk.EventBox.new(), event.add(self.video), then "connect"...
    
        page_box = Gtk.Box( orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, spacing=1 )
        page_box.pack_start( self.video, True, True, 0 )
        self.add(page_box)
    
        GLib.idle_add(self.show_frame)
        #GLib.timeout_add(100, self.show_frame)
        #tried to Thread(target=self.show_frame) w/out loop
    
        self.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
        self.show_all()
    
    def on_video_hover( self, event, result ):
        print("video hover")
    def on_video_clicked( self, event, button ):
        print("video clicked")
    
    def show_frame(self):
        ret, frame = self.capture.read()
        #tried with a while
        if ret:
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            pb = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_data(frame.tobytes(),
                                        GdkPixbuf.Colorspace.RGB,
                                        False,
                                        8,
                                        frame.shape[1],
                                        frame.shape[0],
                                        frame.shape[2]*frame.shape[1])
            self.video.set_from_pixbuf( pb.copy() )
    
        return True #tried changed to False to stop loop

cam = Cam_GTK()
Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer myself : I've found a working solution, coupling multiple usages :

1. Threading a non-blocking GLib.idle_add
2. Separating event calls with an Gtk.EventBox

here is the working code (I think it could be useful for someone with the same troubles) :

```py
import cv2
from time import sleep
import gi

gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, GLib, GdkPixbuf, Gdk, GObject

from threading import Thread

vdo_url="http://my_cam/vdo.mjpg" # simplified, without security

class Cam_GTK(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Cam GTK")

        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(vdo_url)

        self.video = Gtk.Image.new()

        refresh_vdo = Thread(target = self.refresh_video)
        refresh_vdo.daemon= True
        refresh_vdo.start()

        self.event_vdo = Gtk.EventBox.new() #This gives the new events processing for signals
        self.event_vdo.add(self.video)
        self.event_vdo.set_above_child(True)

        self.event_vdo.connect("button-press-event", self.on_video_clicked )
        self.event_vdo.connect("motion-notify-event", self.on_video_hover )

        page_box = Gtk.Box( orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, spacing=1 )
        page_box.pack_start( self.event_vdo, True, True, 0 )
        self.add(page_box)

        self.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
        self.show_all()

    def on_video_clicked( self, event, button ):
        print("clicked")

    def on_video_hover(self, widget, event):
        print("hover")

    def refresh_video( self ):
        while not self.done:
            GLib.idle_add(self.show_frame)
            sleep(0.1) #Wait for Gtk.Image refresh (I guess)

    def show_frame(self):
        ret, frame = self.capture.read()
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        pb = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_data(frame.tobytes(),
                                        GdkPixbuf.Colorspace.RGB,
                                        False,
                                        8,
                                        frame.shape[1],
                                        frame.shape[0],
                                        frame.shape[2]*frame.shape[1])
        self.video.set_from_pixbuf(pb.copy())
        return False #Important to be False not to block


camera = Cam_GTK()
Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

`capture.read()` will **block** until a new frame is available. That will *at least* throttle your event processing loop down to whatever frame rate the video source can deliver. You don't want that.

You'll want to spawn a thread that does `capture.read()` in a loop and then sends freshly read frames to your GUI. That completely decouples GUI event processing from reading the video.

You'll also have to use some flavor of ***message passing***. Direct calls of any GUI functions can potentially block because they might implicitly post some event and wait for it to be processed... which won't happen if your currently executing function was executed by the very same event loop, which is still busy executing that function, so it can't do that other thing, but your API call requires that to get done... so that's how that could block. This is true for Qt (signals and slots) and it's very likely true for GTK as well.

Random search result that looks promising: [Signals and slots in GTK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309208/signals-and-slots-in-gtk)